# Set Content-Charset in Apache HttpClient 4.x

Tags: apache-httpclient-4.x

I am switching my Apache Http Client from 3.x to 4.x.
For the old version, I use following to set my content charset .

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpClient.getParams().setParameter(HttpConnectionParams.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, connectionTimeout);
...  // some more other setting.
httpClient.getParams().setParameter(HttpProtocolParams.HTTP_CONTENT_CHARSET, contentCharset);
```

Now I switched to 4.x, but I am not able finding the way to set the http.protocol.content-charset .

```
httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
Builder builder = RequestConfig.custom();
builder.setConnectionRequestTimeout(connectionTimeout);
... // some other setting
// no function to set the content charset
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The global protocol charset parameter is HC 3.x was silly.

Use `ContentType` to attribute of `HttpEntity` in order to correctly encode / decode the entity content.

```
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
        .build();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://httpbin.org/post");
httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity("stuff", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN.withCharset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
try (CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost)) {
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    if (entity != null) {
        ContentType contentType = ContentType.getOrDefault(entity);
        try (Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(
                entity.getContent(),
                contentType.getCharset() != null ? contentType.getCharset() : StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am able to modify my code with your example. But may your talk more why the global charset was silly? isn't that it save us time from setting the charset in both request and response?

Comment: The charset of content encoding is expected to be included in the `Content-Type` message header. Default charset is also MIME type dependent. This is no such thing as one global content charset applicable to all HTTP messages.

Comment: Lots and lots of in-house applications do not always set content type to include the charset parameter.    Looking at ContentType.TEXT_XML, Apache core 4.4 gets it dead wrong by specifying ISO-8859-1 instead of the default for XML which is, of course, UTF-8.   Then there are the zillions of custom media types used by REST apps.  What about YAML?  I could go on ...

So, no, specifying a default charset is not silly at all in some circumstances.